# Face Detection using OpenCV: How can I get the number of neighbors for each detected face?

Tags: opencv, face-detection

I'm using the C++ function

> void CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale(const Mat& image, vector& objects, double scaleFactor=1.1, int minNeighbors=3, int flags=0, Size minSize=Size(), Size maxSize=Size())

in OpenCV for face detection. As known, the number of neighbors for each detected face can be considered as a confidence score. I'm wondering how I can get the number of neighbors without hacking the source code. I've found OpenCV in Python actually can return the number of neighbors (see [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/objdetect_cascade_classification.html#haardetectobjects)). But how about C++? Is there any function that can directly return such values together with the detected faces?

Thank you very much.